# Converting Flipbook Slider Make it Loop + If it is possible to make it responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, slider, page-flipping

I'm a newbie in Javascripting so plase bear with me anyway here is my question:

Here is the site in question : http://jemmarieann.com/flipbookslideshow/marcbuils-Flippage-c46f6d1/exemples/exemples3.html

So I used this premade Jquery: http://marcbuils.github.io/Flippage/

1. The problem is to turn a page you must click the image I want it so the images flip automatically every 3-5 seconds or so.

   What I was able to do was automatically turn page 1 to page 2 but nothing happens after that. I'm pretty sure I'm missing a lot since I'm a newbie.
2. I was able to make it flip automatically with the help of [dreamweiver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677272/dreamweiver) but it stops when it reaches the last image how        do I make it go back to the first image and loop?

   ```
        <script type="text/javascript">



       setInterval(check, 1000); // trigger check function every 1 sec

       function check()

      {

         var $nextItem = $('.exemples.active')
         .trigger('next')
         .removeClass('active')
         .next('.exemples');


      if ($nextItem.length == 0) $nextItem = $('.exemples').first(); 

          $nextItem.trigger('next').addClass('active');

       };



      </script>
   ```

Here is the body code

```
<body>
<div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="exemples">
    <div><img src="img/1.jpg" style="margin-left: 0px;" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/1.jpg" style="margin-left: -683px;" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/FA_WEB1B.jpg" style="margin-left: 0px;" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/FA_WEB1B.jpg" style="margin-left: -683px;" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/2.jpg" style="margin-left: 0px;" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/2.jpg" style="margin-left: -683px;" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/front.jpg" style="margin-left: 0px;" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/front.jpg" style="margin-left: -683px;" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/3.jpg" style="margin-left: 0px;" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/3.jpg" style="margin-left: -683px;" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/lopulent5.jpg" style="margin-left: 0px;" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/lopulent5.jpg" style="margin-left: -683px;" /></div>
  </div>
  </div>
            <div><a href="#" onClick="$('.exemples:eq(0)').trigger('previous'); return false;">Previous</a> - <a href="#" onClick="javascript:$('.exemples:eq(0)').trigger('next'); return false;">Next</a></div>
        </div>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the plugin and its functionality, i guess you need to auto trigger the **next** option automatically.

Im doing it this way

```
setTimeout(check, 1000); // trigget check function every 1 sec
function check()
{
    $('#exemples').trigger('next');
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it has the same result, only flips from image 1 to image 2.

Comment: Okay Managed to get it to work by using setInterval  instead of setTimeout the problem is now making the slideshow loop

Comment: Editted the question I hope what I'm trying to do is clearer now :)

Comment: @Kitsu: what exactly is the status of question now?

Comment: Well I still can't figure out how to make the animation loop ... so it's partly answered thanks to you but yeah I still haven't figured out how to loop it and if there is some way I can make the jquery responsive...

Comment: @Kitsu: Can u Simulate the same on jsfiddle, so that i can give it a try :)

Comment: I tried, to set up a fiddle but even that I couldn't do right...http://jsfiddle.net/Kitsu/bSNDq/  I have no idea how to link the external scripts but everything necessary resources that I used are located here: http://jemmarieann.com/flipbookslideshow/marcbuils-Flippage-c46f6d1/   I managed to link the images but I don't know how to link the external Jquery